# Mongoose Error when trying to connect to Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, dotenv

so my problem is I'm trying to connect my application to a Mongo DB collection/ database and it won't connect. I have my connection string and port number in a .env file and then I import it into my app.js file, where I try to make a connection.

**Error in the console log :**

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
^
Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make 
sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

**.env file :**

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://Admin:<Password>@cluster0-3t4ed.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
PORT=3000
```

**app.js file :**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
```

**Database :**

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI).then(() => {
  console.log("DB Connected");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
 console.log(`DB Connection Error: ${err.message}`);
});
```

I've already put the connection string in quotes and all, it still didn't work.

I've talked to the MongoDB support and they couldn't help me.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: For your .env: mongodb://username:password@localhost:portnum/dbName <- what do you get?

Comment: and i get the same error as i did before

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving this message because `MONGO_URI` is `undefined` when `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)` is called.

The solution is to call `dotenv.config()` as early as possible in your application (see [dotenv documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage)).

```
// app.js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
```

Comment: I just tried that option and I'm still getting the same error unfortunately ...

Comment: Make sure that the .env file is at you project's root directory (with package.json) or profile its path to dotenv's config() also make sure to restart your Node.js server even if you're using nodemon

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could try.

First of all, instead of using mongoose. You could use the MongoDB module.
You could use

```
require('MongoDB').client;
```

Second in your .env file have you actually put your username and password into the string or make sure that you don't include the

```
<>
```

in your code

Answer (score 0):

ye I actually figured this out in case anyone is wondering. I went into my MongoDB settings, then into Database Access, and I added my current IP address into whitelisting and it seems to work.

this might also be some useful setting I have in my connection code:

```
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  autoIndex: false,
  poolSize: 10,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 0,
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  family: 4
};
mongoose
  .connect(key.MONGO_URI, options)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The 'key' in the .connect method is saved in another file and im importing it into this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create .env file 
    inside .env 
    MONGO_URI=mongo+src://username:password@cluster0......majority
    //
   // Inside app.js or server.js 
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    dotenv.config()

    const mongoose = require('mongoose')

    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    const db = mongoose.connection
    db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
    db.once('open', MONGO_URI => console.log('Connected to Database'))
```

Comment: welcome to SO community, it is encouraged to have some explanation to what your code can help answer the question

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was treated [here](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/9#issuecomment-381504911). I tried it and it worked. You may also consider deleting the trailing `?retryWrites=true&w=majority` incase you change the database name from `test` to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have **mongoose.connect** called twice in your code to different URI. This was the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by:

1. Put .env file at root directory of project.Same directory where your package.json file is located.
2. If this issue arrises when you deploy it such as on Heroku. On heroku it looks up for environmental variables which are declared in heroku. So just follow:
3. Go to your dashboard and in your selected app go to settings tab.
4. Go to Config vars and click reveal vars.
5. Just add your .env variables there in key and value pair.
6. Eg. Put MONGO_URI in Key and mongodb+srv://Admin:@cluster0-3t4ed.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority in Value.
   That's it. You will be able to deploy your app including your .env variables.

Answer (score 0):

At `connect`, way to pass parameter was wrong.
I think this would be work.
try this code

```
connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URL}`).then => () ~~
```

Comment: there are 3 s in your code ```processs```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues once also, what you have to consider are:

1. Is the "app.js" in a serverSide folder different from the clientSide folder, if it is create the ".env" file in the serverSide folder(same folder where you have the "app.js" file).
2. If there's no seperation of files if folders, make sure you are requiring the "require("dotenv").config();" as early as possible in the "app.js" file.