# Why does can I not connect to my data base?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made my database but with the moongoose update my database stop working and gives the error `Can't call`openUri() `on an active connection with different connection string` I don't know why it happens.

#### Code

Here is my mongoose connect code

```js
const urlmon = 'mymongodburl'
mongoose.connect(urlmon, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', MONGO_URI => console.log('Connected to Database'))
```

Comment: See this Stack Overflow post with similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649056/mongoose-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-mongo-db

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this error use `createConnection`
like

```js
const urlmon = 'mymongodburl'
mongoose.createConnection(urlmon, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', MONGO_URI => console.log('Connected to Database'))
```